# What's the purpose of using CSS browser reset code?

Tags: css

Is this valid CSS for browser reset? What does it do? I have been using this for a long time.

```
html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr {margin:0; padding:0;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th {font-size:1em; overflow:hidden; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;}
ul,ol {list-style:none;}
fieldset,img,hr {border:none;}
caption,th {text-align:left;}
table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
td {vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS reset - What exactly does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a version of Eric Meyer's CSS reset. You can read about it here:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on.

And here's a history of why and how it came to life: http://sixrevisions.com/css/the-history-of-css-resets/

Comment: So, I see, it's a long history, and I'm reading it. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a type of CSS reset. It basically resets all the default spacing to zero and all the default alignments to left-top, as well as resetting the font sizes and weights of all the headers. The purpose of CSS resets is to make the website look consistent across all browsers.

---

I don't really like extensive CSS resets, though. Here's mine:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    border: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use `border: none` instead of the equivalent but slightly shorter `border: 0`?

Comment: @thirtydot: I don't find `0` quite as clear. For minification, I do change it to `0`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem to use it with bootstrap wysihtml5 library.
In fact when I try to use italic o bold style, it didnt work. 
To make it works I had to delete tag "i" and "b" from this file.