# Drop down navigation looks right in FF and IE, but not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, cross-browser, navigation

Usually IE is the browser with issues, but it appears to be chrome this time. I am getting the correct positioning for FF and IE for my drop down navigation, but in Chrome it is all over the place and I have no idea why. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this? I have no idea why this is happening. Thanks.

http://lltc.designangler.com

Comment: any reason why you are using `em` to set the width and top position of the sub menus? Also are you using a CSS reset at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do ... It doesn't look like you are.

Comment: The reset is at the top which is the *{} selector which selects all elements and gives them a padding and margin of 0 by default.

Comment: You have errors in your HTML. IDs should be unique. Fix that. Oh, and get rid of the XHTML doctype. XHTML doctypes are for XHTML, while the content is clearly HTML5.