# Why is css "font-family:inherit" affecting color of <select> in Chrome? (with example)

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I was wondering why is `<select>` element different color on few web pages. I noticed that on some pages if there is `font-family:inherit` css property affecting the select element, it would look different - blue!

```
<!-- BLACK -->
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<!-- BLUE -->
<select style="font-family: inherit;">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

[JsFiddle with working example](https://jsfiddle.net/8nr6h74o/2/)

I understand frontend development, and I know about normalize/reset. I am wondering why is `font-family:inherit` affecting color of a `<select>`

Does anyone know why is it so? What is the default value (i.e. inherit) value for the font-family?

[Screenshot showing js fiddle result on mac](https://i.snag.gy/A1RmhZ.jpg)

**EDIT:**

Tony posted a screenshot in comments, `font-family: system-ui;` is affecting look and feel of `<select>`.

**EDIT 2:**

Apparently it is a trend in web design to leave decision on font family to the device - so called native fonts. Therefore forms are also respecting directive and end up rendered as native UI elements.

Comment: you have to actually set the `font-family` to a specific font , then also upload that font to ensure that it always looks the same reguardless of device or browser

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: How does it affect color for you? ... it doesn't for me, only the font type is affected

Comment: It does not affect color. There must be another rule or property that sets the color.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli check out the fiddle please. Are selects different in chrome?

Comment: Selects are the same in Chrome on Windows for me. you might wanna specify OS

Comment: @ZoranAntolović in windows 7 they are the same color in Firefox / Chrome / IE / Safari / Opera

Comment: I've added a screenshot, it's a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: `font-family: system-ui;` is the culprit :) thanks @Tony

Comment: The screenshot shows the up and down arrows as different from the default. You should state this in the question itself and also mention there what OS and browser combination(s) the issue relates to. Also please make sure that the code included in the question is as such sufficient to produce the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is different depending on the browser you are using. Each browser has their own default settings.

You can find a list of default styles across all browsers [here](https://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/). When inspecting elements on chrome you can see default styles labeled as `user agent stylesheet`. An example of this is seen below:

[image]

Many people use a CSS reset file to standardize these settings across browsers. The [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is a popular option to achieve this.

Comment: I do understand that. I'm asking what is actual value of `inherit` for `font-family` on different browsers? Or how to check it? In inspector I can-t see other than `inherit`

Comment: @ZoranAntolović On the chrome inspector default css styles will be labeled as `user agent stylesheet`.

Comment: @ZoranAntolović if you are still having trouble tracking it down, it's possible that the `font-family` style is being inherited from one of your parent tags. The `inherit` setting will use the style of a parent tag, so it is probably not dependent on a `<select>` tags style.

Comment: Please check the fiddle, no parent tags. Inherit is from user-agent but I can't track te actual value. Exact value. Value which would give me the same appearance when i set it to `font-family: {value}`

Comment: @ZoranAntolović I updated the answer to show the user agent style thats setting your select tag. I found it using your fiddle.

Comment: This answer does not address the question at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It address's where the inherited font-family is coming from. So it looks like it is answering the question...

Comment: @Tony thanks! it's this rule: `font-family: system-ui;`. I was looking for this value `system-ui`

Comment: @ZoranAntolović No problem Zoran! If this answers your question please accept this answer to close the question.

Comment: This just says that the initial value of `font-family` is browser-dependent, which is well known and stated in CSS specs. It does not the least address the question why setting `font-family` affects the color (of something).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Actually, as the OP even said that's what he was looking for. So OP was incorrectly asking for the wrong answer and Tony did fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the `font-family` property on form elements cannot be 100% predictably styled across all browsers. I'm not sure if it's a rendering or security reason but in the case of Chrome, the `system-ui` font seems to be the culprit here.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nr6h74o/3/