# Make my website borderless

Tags: html, css, border

How can I make my Website completely Borderless? I always get these Border which is supper annoying. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this? I currently am making a website as a Project for my School, so please be kind.

Comment: Showing us a picture of the result is all very well, but we can't see what is causing that effect without a [mcve]

Comment: show your codes so that everyone can help you fix it

Comment: Inspect your site using the dev tools for your browser (hit f12). You should be able to locate the element that has the top border and appropriately set the border to 0.

Answer (score 3):

By default, all browsers add a margin to `html` and `body` tags. There is much more to this; they are called `user-agent-stylesheet`.

You need to edit your stylesheet (css) and add:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  /** Possibly padding too **/
  padding: 0;
}
```

I suggest reading about **[reset rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
class_name{border-style: none;}
</style>
```