# nav gap in IE11 between two elements

Tags: html, css

There is a gap between the nav bar and the HTML element below the nav bar in IE11. The styles work on Safari and Chrome. Is only on IE that it doesn't.
[image]

As you can see from the image above that a couple of pixels is added to the padding between the nav and the element below. I'm working with Sass and Tailwind. I can't find where this issue is coming from.

[image]

```
    <div class="js-text-controller-options c-text-controller__options hidden" id="text-controls">
        <div class='c-text-controller__languages'>
          {% do action('icl_language_selector') %}
        </div>
        <div class="c-text-controller__sizer">
          <em class="c-text-controller__sizer-text">
            {{__('Adjust text size', 'accessnyctheme')}}
          </em>
          <button class="c-text-controller__sizer-btn btn-text js-text-larger">
            <svg class="icon icon-ui-plus-circle">
              <use xlink:href="#icon-ui-plus-circle"></use>
            </svg>
            <div class="sr-only">{{__('Larger', 'accessnyctheme')}}</div>
          </button>
          <button class="c-text-controller__sizer-btn btn-text js-text-smaller">
            <svg class="icon icon-ui-minus-circle">
              <use xlink:href="#icon-ui-minus-circle"></use>
            </svg>
            <div class="sr-only">{{__('Smaller', 'accessnyctheme')}}</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="o-navigation color-dark-background">
    <div class="logo-access">
      <a href="{{ urlBase }}/">
        <svg class="icon icon-logo-full">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-logo-full"></use>
        </svg><span class="sr-only">{{__('Access NYC', 'accessnyctheme')}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav class="o-navigation__nav nav-inline print:hidden" data-js="site-desktop-nav">{% spaceless %}
      <a class="screen-desktop:hidden" href="#o-mobile-nav" data-js="toggle-nav">
        {{__('Menu', 'accessnyctheme')}}
      </a>
      {% include 'partials/nav.twig' with {this: {style: 'hidden screen-desktop:inline-block'}} %}
      <a class="td-inherit js-toggle-search" href="#search">
        <svg class="icon icon-ui-search">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-ui-search"></use>
        </svg>
        {{__('Search', 'accessnyctheme')}}
      </a>
    {% endspaceless %}</nav>
  </nav>

  <div class="o-mobile-nav color-mid-background print:hidden" id="o-mobile-nav">
    <a class="o-mobile-nav__close" href="#o-mobile-nav" data-js="toggle-nav">
      {{__('close &amp; return to site', 'accessnyctheme')}}
      <svg class="icon icon-ui-x">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-ui-x"></use>
      </svg>
    </a>

    <div class="o-mobile-nav__inner">
      <h4 class="o-mobile-nav__header">
        {{__('Get help now', 'accessnyctheme')}}
      </h4>

      <nav class="nav-block">
        {% include 'partials/nav.twig' %}
        <a href="{{ urlBase }}/?s=">
          <svg class="icon icon-ui-search">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-ui-search"></use>
          </svg>{{__('Search', 'accessnyctheme')}}
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="o-search-box js-search-box print:hidden" id="search" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="o-search-box__inner">
      <div class="usa-grid">
        <div class="usa-width-one-whole">
          <a class="o-search-box__close js-hide-search" href="#content">
            <svg class="icon icon-ui-x">
              <use xlink:href="#icon-ui-x"></use>
            </svg><span class="sr-only">{{__('Close search', 'accessnyctheme')}}</span>
          </a>
```

This is the HTML `base.twig` template. Here is the styles for the navigation bar.

```
/**
 * Nav
 */

// Dependencies
@import 'config/fonts';
@import 'config/colors';
@import 'config/typography';
@import 'config/media';
@import 'config/direction';
@import 'config/dimensions';

// Declarations
@mixin nav-icon {
  svg {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .icon {
    margin-#{$text-direction-end}: .3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -2px
  }
}

.nav-inline {
  @include typography-nav();
  list-style: none;
  text-align: $text-direction-end;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-#{$text-direction-start}: 1em;
  }

  .active {
    font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
  }

  @include nav-icon;
}

.nav-block {
  @include typography-nav();
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $color-grey-dark;
    padding: $spacing-base 0
  }

  .active {
    font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
  }

  @include nav-icon;
}
```

My educated guess that it has to be with an issue regarding `display` tag but can't seem to find where the issue lays. This is how it looks in chrome which is the desire state. [image] Here is a JS fiddle with the base html template and some of the styles. Because of the size of the project it is very difficult to upload all the styles.
https://jsfiddle.net/ky950382/2/

Comment: Please provide an example of the rendered HTML and CSS (the provided styles appear to be SCSS or LESS code). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: @StefanBob which image are you referring to?

Comment: Are you using or willing to try something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [css-reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)

Comment: @alphapilgrim I'm making use of normalize.css

Comment: Have you tried using the F12 Elements inspector?

Comment: if you see the image above in the post, I'm using the f12 elements inspector.

Comment: Have you tried to conditionally target IE11? For example:                      
`@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    // IE10+ CSS here
}`

Comment: adding a `display: block` to the SVG styles fixes the gaps. However, it breaks the logos