# max-width + full-width not working on <input> element when inside grid child

Tags: css

Please see this minimum example:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  max-width: 260px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

I want my `<input>` element to have `260px` width when available, and when on the small screen, use `100%` width.

However, it's not working, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Box Sizing

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `input` styles.

The default `box-sizing` (`content-box`) **doesnt** take the padding into consideration when rendering size. By default, most browsers add padding to inputs in the base browser styles.

This means if you set the width of something to 100px but that something has a left padding of 5px, the total rendered width will be 105px!

This is why a LOT of [CSS resets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do) add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to the reset because it is arguably more intuative.

You can read more about [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) if you're interested.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the rendered `<input>` element is still not `260px`, do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh that's because you're using `max-width` which sets the *maximum* width, not the actual width. Use `width: 260px` 

Comment: I've updated my answer, you need to flip your width and max-width values around.

Comment: But why `max-width: 260px;` + `width: 100%;` won't render `260px`?

Comment: Because it's 100% of the parent container (the div), which when positioned in a grid isnt automatically 100%. Try adding `width: 100%` to the parent div and see what happens.