# Do I still need to add the q and blockquote CSS Reset in 2021? What is the purpose of having this?

Tags: html, css

Do I still need this in 2021?

```
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
```

Can I get an explanation for what these do?

Comment: A reset removes browser default styling of blockquotes (block element) and quote (inline quote) tags. A great explanation of what these are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q. I think you still need them, but a better answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do

Comment: I know what a CSS Reset is... I need to know what those specific rules do...

Comment: Try them in a codepen, you'll see they remove any extra space around the blockquote and q tags.

Answer (score 0):

That's only if you're looking to reset the CSS so those elements will inherit parent styles -- potentially up to `body` and `html`. Semantically, `blockquote` and `q` elements are [used when citing another source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp) according to W3schools.com.

From a user standpoint, you would want to style these as a recognizable quote but to answer the question of purpose: the code is to remove the indent and ensure the default browser styles are removed, your html page may include additional styling that particular code is removing.

See the unstyled `blockquote` and `q` below:

```html
<blockquote>This is a blockquote element</blockquote>
<q>This is a q element</q>
```

A further breakdown of the CSS:

```
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
```

`quotes` is removing [quote styling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/quotes) and

```
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
```

is removing pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` content.

Comment: Why would I need to add quotes: none; ??

Comment: See the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/quotes -- you can use `quotes` to change the automatically applied quote styling. Some devs may prefer adding their own quotes to the text `<q>"This is a famous line"</q>` versus `<q>This is a famous line</q>` (with quotation marks applied automatically)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, semantically speaking, blockquote and q elements are used to cite another source. Whenever I am citing another source I should use the <q> element.

When I use the <q> element, by default it has quotes that get added.

So by using quotes: none; I am removing those quotes that are added by default.

Comment: @Oxin `<q>` is for inline quoting -- `<p>The president commented, <q>Please don't quote me on this.</q></p>` while `<blockquote>` is a 'stand alone' element in between other elements.

Comment: But why would it be in a CSS reset?

Comment: Is it because each browser adds different types of quotes so by using  quotes: none; I can remove those quotes added by default by the browser and from there I can add them manually?

Comment: Essentially, yes. You'd want to 'reset' the CSS (also known as normalize) as it's a guarantee to create similar experiences though I'm not certain how much deviation is within contemporary browsers (Chrome [blink], Edge[blink], Firefox [gecko], Safari[webkit]) if any at all. Since it's part of a CSS reset though, there is probably data/experiences behind its use for older generation browsers (IE11 and lower). Depending on audience, 1-10% of users are still using IE11 and far less using lower. You may still require it to address them. https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share