# How to push two <div> blocks closer to each other in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I made the following code but the two DIV blocks have a blank space between them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background:blue; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <p>123</p>
        </div>

        <div style="background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <p>456</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> > > [image]

I would like to have a code where there is no space between the two blocks. How do I do that?

Comment: Browsers have default stylings for everything. You should add a [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <body style="display:flex; flex-direction: column">
        <div style="background:blue; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <p>123</p>
        </div>

        <div style="background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <p>456</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize the CSS and define `margin: 0`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background:blue; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <p>123</p>
        </div>

        <div style="background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <p>456</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The gap issue is coming because of the default margin applied for the `p` tag. The `*` selector will target all elements. So it is better you can add class for `p` tag and apply your styles.

```css
p.no-margin {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:blue; width: 200px; height: 200px">
  <p class="no-margin">123</p>
</div>

<div style="background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px">
  <p class="no-margin">456</p>
</div>
```