# Correct calculating of vh unit

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a simple page structure like this:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body>div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 97vh;
    width: 97vw;
}

.content {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see in maximized window, height of element `content` is 97% of viewport height, which is what I expect. But as soon as I start to decrease the height of the browser window, this element loses its 97%, approaches 100%, until it reaches a point where it is almost impossible to see the bottom scroll bar.

Shouldn't it still be at 97%? And how can I achieve it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have `.content` with 5000 x 5000 px dimensions?

Comment: Why are you taking `97%` height and width. I don't understand the reason...

Comment: It's just because the `margin` on the body pushes the element offscreen. Add `margin: 0;` to your body and you will see it stays at around 97%

Comment: Ok,  it is `margin` on body, my bad, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the browser applies some default CSS. For the `<body>` it is :

```
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

You need to overwrite the default `margin:8px` by writing :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can also use a ready-made [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do) file.