# Any idea why my local website/visual studio preview display website differently than actual live site?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a fictitious website for a class project using visual studio and my site displays exactly how I want it to locally and through visual studio, but when I upload live to byethost, the CSS is not showing up properly/ there are disparities amongst browsers (which I know is normal). One of the main issues the way the images are displayed on the menu and reservation pages. Locally and in VS my images display horizontally in a scroll bar but on my live site they display stacked on top of each other vertically as if no CSS has been applied.

I am trying to diagnose why some of my CSS does not show up on the live site and find a solution to get my page to read correctly on all browsers. Any tips? I'll attach my HTML and CSS. And here is the link to my draft site: (http://www.townfinedining.byethost13.com/index.html)

```
    <section class="main">
                    <div class="menu_imagebox">
                            <div class="scroll">
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/salmon2.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="Salmon plated like starfish">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/chicken2.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="Red pepper on roasted chicken">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/app2jpg.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="edamame, dumplings, chicken karagge">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/juicy.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="sliced wagyu beef held by chopsticks">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/friedrice.jpg" loading="lazy"
                                                            class="responsive" alt="bowl of fried rice with egg on top">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/springrolls.jpg" loading="lazy"
                                                            class="responsive" alt="plate of springrolls">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/pho.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="close up bowl of pho with sriracha sauce on top">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/sushi_boat.jpg" loading="lazy"
                                                            class="responsive" alt="two decorite mini boats filled with coconut shell and sushi on top">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/dumpling.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="bowl of bright orange dumpling soup">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/wagyu2.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="pan of sliced wagyu beef surrounded by wasabi">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/chicken.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="chicken kebabs and peppers">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/app.jpg" loading="lazy" class="responsive"
                                                            alt="takoyaki fried octopus ball appetizer">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="images/sushiball.jpg" loading="lazy"
                                                            class="responsive" alt="plate of crafted sushi balls">
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </section>
```

CSS:

```
    .menu_imagebox {
    max-width: 80rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .scroll {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 2.5rem 0;
    cursor: default;
    overflow: scroll hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-padding: 0px 1.25rem;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    }
    .card {
    width: 16rem;
    height: auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin: 0 0.75rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    }
    .card-image {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 110%;
    }
    img.responsive {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;      
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn about css resets : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do

Comment: @MisterJojo this is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Also, check how you're linking CSS or any other assets (relative links, varying OS styles of directory structures etc...) 
Start by using the developer tools panel in the live site, check the console for any errors, and adjust accordingly. 
@MisterJojo's comment here is valid, just thought to share something relevant that you're gonna deal with when pushing to any prod