# I am having trouble positioning my list element in my nav element

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles making my list go to the left of my nav element. I have tried to make the nav element relative and list absolute, but that just makes the words overlap each other.

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul style="list-style: none">
    <li>#stayhome</li>
    <li>anime</li>
    <li>queue</li>
    <li>discord</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `<ul>` has non-zero `padding-left`.

Comment: Useful reading: [CSS reset - What exactly does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579120/1115360)

Comment: If you can, use grid and flex for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `justify-content` property is irrelevant here - it only applies to elements in a Flex or Grid layout.

The issue here is the default margin/padding on the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

You might also want to set the `line-height` on the `<nav>` so that the list items are more centred.

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 48px;
}

nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul style="list-style: none">
    <li>#stayhome</li>
    <li>anime</li>
    <li>queue</li>
    <li>discord</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by setting display property of ul to flex

```
  nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 48px;
  }
  ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
} 

<nav>
   <ul style="list-style: none">
     <li>#stayhome</li>
     <li>anime</li>
     <li>queue</li>
     <li>discord</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```