# Same input types showing different box sizes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to size my input fields in the my particular  in css

my html code is

```
<fieldset>
        <!-- Name-->
        <label id="name-label">Name<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
        <!-- Email-->
        <label id="email-label">Email<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
        <!-- Age-->
        <label id="number-label">Age<input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter your age" min="10" max="99" required/>
        <!-- Select form-->
        <label id="role">
          Which option best describes your current role?
          <select id="dropdown" name="survey-form">
            <option value="">Select current role</option>
            <option value="1">Student</option>
            <option value="2">Full time job</option>
            <option value="3">Full time learner</option>
            <option value="4">Prefer not to say</option>
            <option value="5">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
```

I am resizing it using

```
fieldset:first-of-type input,select{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
    
}
```

as I have four fieldset I am using first-of-type

the problem is the select field is shorter then rest of the input field

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jeUl.png)

Comment: When I run the code you have given the select and the other inputs are the same width. Could you create a runnable snippet which you have tested does definitely show the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. Also what browser is giving this problem? I tested on WIndows 10 Edge/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In Your HTML Code You Need To Give The Same Value In The Option And You Was Give You The Value 1,2,3,4,etc. It Is Not Good For A Good Coder That's Why I Think You Got The Error.

```html
<fieldset>
        <!-- Name-->
        <label id="name-label">Name<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
        <!-- Email-->
        <label id="email-label">Email<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
        <!-- Age-->
        <label id="number-label">Age<input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter your age" min="10" max="99" required/>
        <!-- Select form-->
        <label id="role">
          Which option best describes your current role?
          <select id="dropdown" name="survey-form">
            <option value="Select current role" selected>Select current role</option>
            <option value="Student">Student</option>
            <option value="Full time job">Full time job</option>
            <option value="Full time learner">Full time learner</option>
            <option value="Prefer not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

## box-sizing

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your inputs or i recommend to add this property to all HTML elements:

```css
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

What is box-sizing ?

> The CSS box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

Learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

What is a universal selector (*)?

> The universal selector (*) selects all HTML elements on the page.

Learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp#The%20CSS%20Universal%20Selector)

---

## Reset browser initial values

I suggest that you always dedicate a part of your code to resetting browsers' Initial values

A simple way to do this is:

```css
  *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: inherit;
    /* and more */
  }
```

Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)

Answer (score 0):

Define input field css explicitely

```
fieldset:first-of-type input{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: 99.3%;
    min-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(218, 218, 218); 
}
select{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 2em;
    border: 2px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
}
```

[image: Img]