# How to Fix Button Background

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble with fixing my button in CSS. I have my button styled correctly, but for some reason the background behind the button itself is white still.

The code for my button & links, as I think it may be an issue with my links as well.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="s1btn">
<a href="#" target="_blank" tabindex="1">GitHub
</a></button></div>
```

**CSS for button:**

```
.s1btn a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
background-color: #f36dcb;
border: black 1px solid;
border-radius: 3px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
}`

.s1btn a:hover {
background: #844421;
}

.s1btn a:active {
background: #b36b43;
padding-top: 3px;
}
```

**CSS for all links:**

```
links {
font-size: medium;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 50px;
color: #844421;
font-weight: 500;
}

.hLink {
margin-right: 30px;
}
```

`
**Screenshot of button:**

[Broken Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYmM9.png)

I tried to comment out different sections of my button but that didn't help me target the problem to resolve the issue. I also tried to inspect the website itself, to figure out what was causing the background of my button to remain white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers have default styles for buttons, a tags, etc. Your css is only selecting the `<a>` tag in the `<button>` tag, so no styles are being applied to the `<button>` itself. You can reset the styles of the button with this:

```
button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can see more on resetting the button styles here: https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/

Comment: thank you, that helped! So also  if I use reset css, would this solve this issue for me to style my css more freely?

Comment: Yes, in fact it's common for developers to use a reset css file to remove all default styling. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579120/20913924) goes into more detail.