# The size of my input field and button with same width and height appears different

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    background-color: #EEF0F4;
}

input {
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: #432000;
    background-color: #DCE1EB;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 10em;
    height: 3em;
}

button {
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: #FDFDFD;
    background-color: #AC485A;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 10em;
    height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <img src="assets/cat.png" alt="cat image">
    <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="Bread">
    <button id="add-button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

[input field box model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lhXz.png)
[button box model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E374K.png)

I can't resolve as to why the innermost aspect/element in box model is using different sizes for the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely coming from your browser and not your CSS.

Because modern browsers like to add in their own custom styling first, many developers like to remove this browser styling with a [reset CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)

See also [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS 2](https://cssdeck.com/blog/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/)

The simplest fix is to add `box-sizing: border-box;` as this is where the issue is actually coming from.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEF0F4;
}

input {
  margin-top: 13px;
  color: #432000;
  background-color: #DCE1EB;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  margin-top: 13px;
  color: #FDFDFD;
  background-color: #AC485A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="assets/cat.png" alt="cat image">
  <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="Bread">
  <button id="add-button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

Now they are sized the same:
Input:
[image: Input sizing]

Button:
[image: Button sizing]

Answer (score 0):

You should use px so the height will be the same mandatory

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEF0F4;
}

input {
  margin-top: 13px;
  color: #432000;
  background-color: #DCE1EB;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 40px;  //use the px unit
}

button {
  margin-top: 13px;
  color: #FDFDFD;
  background-color: #AC485A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 40px; //use the px unit
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="assets/cat.png" alt="cat image">
  <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="Bread">
  <button id="add-button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Using the _Inspect Element_ tool on the browser shows that these elements are still different sizes