# Body and body::before positioning

Tags: css, css-position, pseudo-element

I'm new to HTML and CSS and have been trying to create an effect where I have a background colour set to black and an image containing noise set on top if it. I've now managed to blend them how I wanted but was wondering if this is the correct way of doing things? I'm also wondering how the positioning relates in this scenario. From what I've read I gather that absolutely positioned elements refers to the positioning of the parent element which has to be relative. Is it fine to apply position: relative; to the body?

```
body {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

body::before {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 250 250' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='noiseFilter'%3E%3CfeTurbulence type='fractalNoise' baseFrequency='6.5' numOctaves='5' stitchTiles='stitch'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' filter='url(%23noiseFilter)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 20%;
  content: "";
  background-size: cover;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

I've tried searching for answers online but I have a hard time finding if im doing this correctly. Can someone more knowledgeable please explain to me what I'm accomplishing here?

Comment: no, it is not the correct way as you can combine a background image and background color in one syntax. No need to create a pseudo-element for that! PS: for other cases where you actually want to sue `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` you could also use `inset: 0`

Comment: @tacoshy my first thought as well - but the `mix-blend-mode: screen` part can't be achieved by just specifying multiple backgrounds, I suppose?

Comment: @CBroe you might be right. Unfortunately I cannot check the intended outcome to see if we really need `mix-blend-mode` in the first place

Comment: There's nothing inherently 'incorrect' about putting a before pseudo element on the body element, and it is necessary in some situations, e.g. wanting to set opacity to less than 1 on a background image (when you wouldn't want the whole body to pick up that opacity). This could also be true in a mix-blend-mode case, depending on what you want to blend with what.

Comment: @tacoshy refering to the last comment, I can't see how stating multiple backgrounds would work in this case where I want to lower the opacity of the image.

Answer (score -1):

Very close!

With the sort of thing your heading for (an absolute-positioned psuedo element) you just need to do a couple of things:

1. Ensure the the `width` and `height` properties of `::before` are set to `100%` so they fill up the element they're attached to.
2. you can avoid setting all `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` values by using `inset: 0` as @tacoshy points out
3. (optional) you may want to include on the `body` style: `min-height: 100vh` to ensure that the body is 100% of the *visible height* of the screen (which doesn't work very well on the snippets)

I've added some content to the `body` so you can see how it behaves. You can also see that additional styling might be added by the browser (see: [Reset CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11578819/15291770), [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11578902/15291770))

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

body::before {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 250 250' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='noiseFilter'%3E%3CfeTurbulence type='fractalNoise' baseFrequency='6.5' numOctaves='5' stitchTiles='stitch'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' filter='url(%23noiseFilter)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 20%;
  content: "";
  background-size: cover;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>P1</p>
<p>P1</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: just no... that approach was not incorrect. if you want to cut on left and bottom use `inset: 0` for all 4 directions instead.

Comment: @tacoshy ok, I wasn't aware you could use `inset: 0` instead. Are there other things at fault or that can be improved that was worthy of a downvote?

Comment: that is not really worth an answer. the points you address are technical not wrong to start with. You just pointing out other ways to let the element spread the whole parent element which is just commantary.

Comment: I suppose so, but I only include them because OP says they're new to HTML and CSS and CSS particularly is a continual minefield. And also because I wanted to highlight that _not_ having a method to spread the element within its parent would show my answer to not work at all if they didn't already have content in the `body` element; it highlights the behaviours of CSS, which again are important for OP since they're new to all this.