How do I remove the extra space above my rendered <div> container in SharePoint Online?
How do I remove the extra space above my rendered  container in SharePoint Online?
screenshot of extra space above welcome message
See below for  container java script code inserted into SharePoint Online page using the JS Modern Script Editor web part:
    <div id="welcomeContainer"; line-height:0px>
      <p id="WelcomeMsg"></p>
      <p id="OurTeam"></p>
      <p id="ThisSite"></p>
      <p id="Excited"></p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var displayName = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
      var firstName = displayName.split(" ")[1]; // Extract the first name

      // Set styles for the welcome message
      document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg").style.color = "black";
      document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg").style.fontSize = "25px"; // Set font size
      document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg").style.fontFamily = "Segoe UI, sans-serif"; // Set font    family
      document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg").innerHTML = "Hi " + firstName + ", Welcome!";

    </script>

I tried adding line-height="0" to the container  but did not work.

Try by adding margin-top:0px to the div with id welcomeContainer

This question may help you out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do

why are you hitting the DOM 4 times with document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg") here?

try
const welcomeMessage = document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg");
welcomeMessage.style.marginTop = "0";
welcomeMessage.style.paddingTop = "0";

The space you're seeing is most likely padding or margin. Experiment with what works.
In general a great way to diagnose things like this is with the browser dev tools which you can open in most browsers by pressing F12. If you then push Ctrl, Alt, C you can mouse over the element and it will colour code where the space is coming from. Green is padding, Orange is margin.

why are you hitting the DOM twice with document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg") here?

Q: why are you hitting the DOM twice with document.getElementById("WelcomeMsg") here?
A: Followed document.getElementById examples - As opposed to doing what instead?

MarkSchultheiss is right of course. I just copied from the question.
@Dan, Mark suggests that you assign the element to a const first. I've updated my code to reflect that
